# Add dynamic input type on change of select box in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring

I have a  box which do have the options like "Input","Select","Check","Radion". 
On select of any option, i need to populate corresponding html type like
if i select input, i would like to populate `<input type="text"/>`
if i select select , i would like to populate `<select> box`
if i select input, i would like to populate `<input type="checkbox"/>` tag.

all this things should do dynamically.

How can i add to spring:form tag for the new generated html type.
So that i will be adding the new values to command object.

Kindly suggest how can i do this.

Thanks,
Rishi.

Comment: You are much more likely to get good help if you provide a code example of what you have tried and why it didn't work. Specifically from the SO help: " Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<select id="multiOptions" name="multiOptions" style="width: 214px">
 <option value="S" selected="selected">--Select Input Type --</option>
<option value="C">Checkbox</option>
<option value="R">Radio</option>
<option value="B">Button</option>
</select>
<div id="radios">
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="option">option1</input>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="option">option2</input>
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="option">option1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="option">option2</input>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="option1" name="option"/>
    <input type="button" value="option2" name="option"/>
</div>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#checkboxes').hide();
$('#radios').hide();
$('#buttons').hide();
$("#multiOptions").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "R" ) {
       $('#radios').show();
       $('#checkboxes').hide();
       $('#buttons').hide();
    }
 else if ($(this).val() == "C") {
     $('#checkboxes').show();
     $('#radios').hide();
     $('#buttons').hide();
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "B"){
     $('#checkboxes').hide();
     $('#radios').hide();
     $('#buttons').show();
    }
    else { 
        $('#checkboxes').hide();
        $('#radios').hide(); 
        $('#buttons').hide();
         }
});
});
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/9NkVC/24/

Comment: Hi Amit,
Thanks for the update, So would all the values will map to command object?

Comment: Yep, Got it Amit. Thanks alot for your help.
Thanks,Rishi

Comment: On your Left hand side there is a sign of right just click on it